# Can I use placeholder in annotation class level in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

Is possible to use placeholder SPEL in annotation placed at class or interface level in spring boot??

**Interface**

```
@CustomAnnotation(name = "${my.property.value}")
public interface DummyEntityMapper {}
```

**application.yml**

```
my:
 property:
  name: dummy_value
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work out of the box, whatever code that processes your annotation needs to resolve the placeholder.

Using the `ConfigurableBeanFactory`...

```java
/**
 * Resolve the given embedded value, e.g. an annotation attribute.
 * @param value the value to resolve
 * @return the resolved value (may be the original value as-is)
 * @since 3.0
 */
@Nullable
String resolveEmbeddedValue(String value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I see, my problem is that @CustomAnnotation comes from another imported library and I cannot make any change

Comment: Whether or not you can compensate for it (resolve the value) later, entirely depends on exactly the annotation's purpose is.

Comment: It's a mybatis interface entity mapper. The annotation is related with declare the circuit breaker tenant during the application context building. I don't know if there's a workaround to save this scenario